# Exception has occurred: KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm attempting to use python to scan an excel file of stock data and help screen it. The following error is occurring however. It should ask what file you want to screen, and then apply a series of conditions to determine which stocks meet the screening parameters. Then save it as another spreadsheet with what passed the screens.

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'Symbol'
  File "D:\Program Files\Projects\TrendTemplate.py", line 27, in <module>
    stock=str(stocklist["Symbol"][i])
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter

yf.pdr_override() 
start =dt.datetime(2017,12,1)
now = dt.datetime.now()

root = Tk()
ftypes = [(".xlsm","*.xlsx",".xls")]
ttl  = "Title"
dir1 = 'C:\\'
filePath = askopenfilename(filetypes = ftypes, initialdir = dir1, title = ttl)


stocklist = pd.read_excel(filePath)
#stocklist=stocklist.head()

exportList= pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock', "RS_Rating", "50 Day MA", "150 Day Ma", "200 Day MA", "52 Week Low", "52 week High"])

for i in stocklist.index:
    stock=str(stocklist["Symbol"][i])
    RS_Rating=stocklist["RS Rating"][i]

    try:
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, now)

        smaUsed=[50,150,200]
        for x in smaUsed:
            sma=x
            df["SMA_"+str(sma)]=round(df.iloc[:,4].rolling(window=sma).mean(),2)


        currentClose=df["Adj Close"][-1]
        moving_average_50=df["SMA_50"][-1]
        moving_average_150=df["SMA_150"][-1]
        moving_average_200=df["SMA_200"][-1]
        low_of_52week=min(df["Adj Close"][-260:])
        high_of_52week=max(df["Adj Close"][-260:])
        try:
            moving_average_200_20 = df["SMA_200"][-20]

        except Exception:
            moving_average_200_20=0

        #Condition 1: Current Price > 150 SMA and > 200 SMA
        if(currentClose>moving_average_150>moving_average_200):
            cond_1=True
        else:
            cond_1=False
        #Condition 2: 150 SMA and > 200 SMA
        if(moving_average_150>moving_average_200):
            cond_2=True
        else:
            cond_2=False
        #Condition 3: 200 SMA trending up for at least 1 month (ideally 4-5 months)
        if(moving_average_200>moving_average_200_20):
            cond_3=True
        else:
            cond_3=False
        #Condition 4: 50 SMA> 150 SMA and 50 SMA> 200 SMA
        if(moving_average_50>moving_average_150>moving_average_200):
            #print("Condition 4 met")
            cond_4=True
        else:
            #print("Condition 4 not met")
            cond_4=False
        #Condition 5: Current Price > 50 SMA
        if(currentClose>moving_average_50):
            cond_5=True
        else:
            cond_5=False
        #Condition 6: Current Price is at least 30% above 52 week low (Many of the best are up 100-300% before coming out of consolidation)
        if(currentClose>=(1.3*low_of_52week)):
            cond_6=True
        else:
            cond_6=False
        #Condition 7: Current Price is within 25% of 52 week high
        if(currentClose>=(.75*high_of_52week)):
            cond_7=True
        else:
            cond_7=False
        #Condition 8: IBD RS rating >70 and the higher the better
        if(RS_Rating>70):
            cond_8=True
        else:
            cond_8=False
        
        if(cond_1 and cond_2 and cond_3 and cond_4 and cond_5 and cond_6 and cond_7 and cond_8):
            exportList = exportList.append({'Stock': stock, "RS_Rating": RS_Rating, "50 Day MA": moving_average_50, "150 Day Ma": moving_average_150, "200 Day MA": moving_average_200, "52 Week Low": low_of_52week, "52 week High": high_of_52week}, ignore_index=True)
    except Exception:
        print("No data on "+stock)

print(exportList)

newFile=os.path.dirname(filePath)+"/ScreenOutputTrendTemplate.xlsx"

writer= ExcelWriter(newFile)
exportList.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1")
writer.save()
```

Comment: can you share the header for stocklist? Or just provide output of stocklist.head(20)

Comment: Also, the way you convert a dataframe column to string is not how you think it is. Sample is `df['column_name'].astype(str)`  or `df.column_name.astype(str)`

Comment: please post the stacktrace in its entirety.

Comment: Joe you asking about it caused me to go look into it more, the spreadsheet itself was messed up so the header was not where it was supposed to be. I got it working now, thanks!